# php problema con la barra invertida

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con el carácter especial \ (barra invertida) en php.
Si tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$f="aboca.png";
$ficheros[]=array("title" => $f, "description" => $f, "image" => "select\".$f");
pirnt_r($ficheros);
```

El resultado es:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => aboca.png [description] => aboca.png [image] => select".aboca.png )
```

y necesito que el resultado sea el siguiente:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => aboca.png [description] => aboca.png [image] => select\aboca.png )
```

ya sé que `\` es un caracter especial y he probado con varias combinaciones pero no hay manera.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debe funcionar (\\):

```
$f="aboca.png";
$ficheros[]=array("title" => $f, "description" => $f, "image" => "select\\".$f");
pirnt_r($ficheros);
```

Tambien existe la  [constante de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php) `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
$f = "aboca.png";
$ficheros = array("title" => $f, "description" => $f, "image" => "select" . "\\" . $f );
print_r($ficheros);
```

Podes verificarlo en 
http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/txiq-vm3q

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque te sobran comillas al final:

```
 "select\\".$f");
```

despues de la $f

Comment: Edita tu respuesta o añade un comentario en lugar de añadir una nueva respuesta para un comentario

Comment: Tienes razón y tambien me faltaba una coma al final, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En PHP los literales los puedes definir de diferentes maneras si lo englobas con coma doble **"** PHP tiene en cuenta los caracteres especiales \n \t \? etc...

Mejor usar **'** , tú código con comillas simples:

```
$f='aboca.png';
$ficheros[]=array('title' => $f, 'description' => $f, 'image' => 'select\'.$f);
pirnt_r($ficheros);
```

En caso de definir literales usando coma doble, debes usar `\\`

```
$f="aboca.png";
$ficheros[]=array("title" => $f, "description" => $f, "image" => "select\\$f");
pirnt_r($ficheros);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas de resolverlo, tomando en cuenta que la idea principal es escapar el caracter.

1. Escapando el '\' backSlash  
   Si un string está delimitado con comillas dobles ("), PHP interpretará más secuencias de escape como caracteres especiales:[mas info](http://php.net/language.types.string)

**solución**: '\\' barra invertida

```
$ficheros = array("title" => $f, "description" => $f, "image" => "select\\".$f);
```

También puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$ficheros = array("title" => $f, "description" => $f, "image" => "select\\.$f");
```

**Nota:** Si usas comillas dobles (") puedes poner la varible php dentro sin ningun problema.